# How to add a new line of code in an LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am writing an **LLVM pass**, in which i need to **add a a line of code** :

`list ObserverBoardInterface* ObserverList;`.

I need to add this at a particular point in the program. So **how would I write a pass that directly adds this line of code (what approach should i take) and how do i enter this code at a particular point using the LLVM pass (signal at which point this change needs to be made)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a set of instructions, you can write your C/C++ code and compile it to llvm bitcode with command:

> clang test.cpp -emit-llvm -S -o test.ll

then open ***test.ll*** with your favorite editor and read the set of instructions.
Once, you can write your own pass, which:

1. will create a function with a set of instructions obtained above and
2. will find a point for call of this function